# Does RLS apply on the dashboard tiles and are they cached?

Tags: powerbi

I'm exploring Power BI RLS. I understand that roles (along with the filter criteria) are to be created in the PBI desktop and users are to be added into the roles via the PBI service. Then, when a user opens the report, the RLS will automatically show only those rows that satisfy the filter criteria.

This question is to ask - how does RLS behave with dashboard tiles? For example - say visuals from multiple reports (each report having RLS) are pinned as tiles onto a dashboard.

1. Does opening a dashboard ensure that RLS is applied to the pinned visuals?
2. I have read it somewhere that dashboards retain the tile values for 15 minutes. Does this also mean that RLS is also cached? For example - say RLS membership is updated, then will the dashboard tile immediately reflect the visual tile based on the new RLS?

Answer (score 1):

yes RLS applies to pinned visuals in a dashboard. it applies in the same way as a report. Cache is a browser setting. You might also want to explore Goals while you on the same topic.